# Build Sql Select Query without using fmt.Sprintf

Tags: mysql, go

Long story short, I want to change in the select portion of sql query with prepared statement or anything else instead of using `fmt.Sprintf`, because I don't want user input going directly into the query.

I'm trying to select a two specific columns from the database based on user's request. It works just fine if I hardcode the column name like this (I simplified the query for this question):

```golang
query := `SELECT
   m.first_name,
   m.created_at
FROM
   member AS m
INNER JOIN device AS d
   ON d.member_id = m.member_id`
WHERE m.member_id = ?
```

However, it doesn't work if I use this query:

```golang
query := `SELECT
   m.?,
   m.created_at
FROM
   member AS m
INNER JOIN device AS d
   ON d.member_id = m.member_id`
WHERE m.member_id = ?
```

For both queries, I used [`*sql.DB.QueryContext`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryContext) to bind the placeholder with arguments: `db.QueryContext(ctx, query, args)`. After reviewing all example codes in sql driver, I realized that I cannot dynamically bind the select portion with arguments in prepared statement (Correct me if I'm wrong). I thought this works as ? mark in where conditions.

Is there any better way in [`database/sql` package](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryContext) to build Sql Select portion dynamically without use user input directly in the query?

Comment: for what is the question mark? a placeholder that will not work with prepared statemenst.

Comment: @nbk I want to dynamically pass the column name based on user input like first name or nickname or previous name. I found out that a placeholder doesn't work in select query, so I am asking if there is any better way to build select portion dynamically or not.

Comment: see my answer, that can't be done with placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use placeholders not in that way only to replace values not column names or table names

See http://go-database-sql.org/prepared.html

```
MySQL               PostgreSQL            Oracle
=====               ==========            ======
WHERE col = ?       WHERE col = $1        WHERE col = :col
VALUES(?, ?, ?)     VALUES($1, $2, $3)    VALUES(:val1, :val2, :val3)
```